# Bootstrap Text on Right of Breadcrumb Bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 with the default theme.  I have breadcrumbs using:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="active">Data</li>
</ol>
```

How might I get text properly aligned on the right side of the breadcrumb bar?  I couldn't find a way in the Bootstrap documentation.

Edit:  I don't want the breadcrumbs right-aligned.  I would like a separate span of text to be shown on the right side of the bar (since is it kind of wasted space).

Comment: You want breadcrumbs to be right aligned?

Comment: Sorry, @Adrift good call.  I edited my question.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between "right aligned" and "separate span of text on the right side"? Perhaps post an image of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I tried just add an <li> with pull-right, the breadcrumb separator showed up before my right justified item (which is not what I wanted).

I wanted a search button at the right end of the breadcrumb bar, so I did this:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <form>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <ol class="breadcrumb" style="height:100%;">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="active">Data</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

By using the breadcrumb class on the outer div, you get the breadcrumb background on the whole thing.  You may need to play with the padding on the outermost div, depending on the height of what's in your right div.

Answer (score 12):

**Update 2019 using Bootstrap 4.3**

The solution with `class="pull-right"` doesn't work with Bootstrap 4. 
I've been able to put text on the right using `ml-auto`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672730

```
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item ml-3">
      <a href="#reserver">Réserver</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="#about">À propos</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="#horaires">Horaires</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="#avis">Avis</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ml-auto">Détails établissement</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 6):

No big deal, just use Bootstrap's `pull-right` class:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="active">Data</li>
  <li class="pull-right">Right Aligned Text</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This solution works great. Add some CSS to remove separator. `.breadcrumb > li + li.pull-right:before {content: none;}`

Answer (score 1):

Fwiw: using Bootstrap 4, I adapted the accepted answer to look like this:

```html
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/operations">Operations</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Choose document set</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    <div class="breadcrumb auto-ml">
        <a href="/user/edit_user_profile">Julie Operator</a>
        &nbsp; | &nbsp;
        <a href="/user/sign-out">Sign out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Text on right of breadcrumb bar with Bootstrap 4]

Hth someone

dtk

**PS:** [@Aikawa Towa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55460883/1666398) seems to apply the same mechanism, does look tidier, though.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<div class="row">
    <ol class="breadcrumb col-md-8">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
        <li class="active">Data</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Something else on the right
    </div>
</div>
```