# Right align text within Bootstrap 4 breadcrumbs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to right align a link within bootstrap 4's breadcrumb class. I did this pretty easily with pull-right class in BS3, however BS4's 'float-right' does not do the job.

For example:

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
    <a href="Basket" class="float-right">Basket</a>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

In this case it doesnt float-right at all and I cannot seem to work out a solution. How can I do this?

Comment: [A later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107401/how-to-insert-a-button-right-of-the-breadcrumb-elements-in-bootstrap-4) provides a better solution I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap dropped `pull-left` and `pull-right` in v4 and replaced it with `float-left` and `.float-right.`

Here below is a work around with the new flex-box I hope it helps

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>

    </ol>   
<a href="#">Basket</a>  
</nav>
```

You can refer to this section of the Bootstrap documentation [Bootstrap 4 Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt keep the link within the breadcrumbs (visually), but does float it right.

Comment: edit: im using bootswatch theme lumen, with the default bootstrap 4 theme your solution works. but has a lot of additional padding because of the duplicate breadcrumb class. thanks

Comment: @Adam91 I also encountered a lot of additional padding. Did you solve that? In the official documentation they also used duplicate breadcrumb classes, which I don't understand... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/

Comment: There's no reason to use the breadcrumb class twice, and it's not the proper structure. There's also no reason to use d-flex, since `.breadcrumb` is `display:flex`

Answer (score 19):

**Update 2018 Bootstrap 4.1**

`float-*` doesn't work with flexbox.

The better way to align breadcrumbs items to the right now that Bootstrap 4 is flexbox is to use auto-margins. Simply don't make the last item a `breadcrumb-item` to remove the divider and `ml-auto` to push it to the right.

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data</li>
        <li class="ml-auto">Basket</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

***EDIT:***

> "How about if I have two `<li>`'s that I want to right aligned? If I use
>   two `<li class="ml-auto">Basket</li>`, one is in the middle."

In that case you would just use `ml-auto` on the leftmost (first) of the 2 `li`'s.

https://www.codeply.com/go/6ITgrV7pvL

Comment: How about I have two <li>'s that I want to right aligned? If I use two  `<li class="ml-auto">Basket</li>`, one is in the middle.

Comment: No, you would just use it on the left (first) of the 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use just like this in Bootstrap v4+

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb justify-content-center">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call **ml-auto** class in the first item of breadcrumb :)

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item ml-auto"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">Menu</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ml-auto on the list item to change the effect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).