# How to insert a button right of the breadcrumb elements in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following breadcrumbs in use:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">My Account</li>
</ol>
```

Now what I want is to insert a button on the same line as the breadcrumbs, but have it `float: right`, like:

```
Home  /  My Account    < ---------- Space goes here ---------- >    Button
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">My Account</li>

    <span style="float: right;">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
          Create New User
        </button>
      </li>
    </span>

</ol>
```

Also I tried to use the bootstrap class `float-right` with no result.

How could I place the button on the same line with the breadcrumbs but float it right? Also there should be no slash `/` between the last breadcrumb and the button.

Comment: Flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/jkbcc406/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution would be to take the `button` out of the `ol` and position it absolutely. This would require you to wrap the `ol` and `button` in a container and set `position:relative;` on the container:

```css
.nav-container {
  position:relative;
}
button {
  position:absolute;
  right:1rem;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="nav-container">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active">My Account</li>
  </ol>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Create New User</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple approach using bootstrap 4 util classes:

```
<div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0 p-0">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">My Account</li>
  </ol>

  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Create New User</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use bootstrap class **float-left** and **float-right** in ol and ul with **nav** class

```
<div class="nav-container">
  <ol class="breadcrumb float-left">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">My Account</li>
   </ol>
  <ul class="nav  float-right">
  <li>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Create New User</button>
  </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. Elements below the `nav-container` get placed between the breadcrumbs and the button. Also, the button is not on the same line as the breadcrumbs.

Comment: yes, I tested it with bootstrap 4, it's not working as it shoud be

Comment: `float-*` won't work with flexbox, and `breadcrumb` is now flexbox. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672730/171456).