# How to right align multiple texts with Bootstrap 4 breadcrumbs?

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I want to create a breadcrumb using Bootstrap 4.1 so that the sitemap path shows on the left and registers and displays login links on the right. The following is a schematic view of what I want to achieve:

```
Home/Blog/post                                                Register/Login
```

By following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48159812/right-align-text-within-bootsrap-4-breadcrumbs/51672730?noredirect=1#comment90371563_51672730), I was able to use `ml-auto` to move the "Login" link to the right. If I use `ml-auto` on "Register",  it shows up in the middle.

My Code:

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">post</li>
        <li class="ml-auto">Register</li>
        <li class="ml-auto">Login</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

End Result:

```
Home/Blog/post                    Register                        Login
```

Comment: Why this question is down voted?

Comment: probably because its nothing to do with django

Comment: This was already answered in the comments of the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the ml-auto from login, you only need one ml-auto for it to apply to everything after it

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">post</li>
        <li class="ml-auto">Register</li>
        <li>Login</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```