# Bootstrap-4 : Align breadcrumbs with header

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a header and some breadcrumbs on a page that currently are not aligned together:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/ondeph4a/2/

```html
<br>
<nav>
<ol>
<h1 class="header-title">
My Title Page
</h1>
</ol>
</nav>


<!-- Breadcrumbs -->
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
</ol>
</nav>
```

I'm trying to get my Breadcrumbs to align with my header title "Product x ..." so that the breadcrumbs are directly underneath the header, instead of being over to the left like they are now.

I'm sorry I know this question is super common, I've been trying to use solutions already asked/solved on stackoverflow like this one: [Right align text within Bootstrap 4 breadcrumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48159812/right-align-text-within-bootstrap-4-breadcrumbs/48160092)

But have not been able to get my breadcrumsb aligned nicely. Any help is much appreciated; thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach will help you:

```
  <!-- Breadcrumbs -->
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="mx-auto">
      <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
        </ol>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It results in this:

[image]

Or try this:

```
<!-- Breadcrumbs -->
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item ml-4"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Data</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

It results in this:

[image]

Comment: check this jsfiddle; your code centers the breadcrumbs but i want them to be aligned with the title https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/ondeph4a/2/

Comment: this works in the jsfiddle but in my local code it still appears far to the left for some reason